# accidentally deleted mysql database

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench

I was working with netbean's database explorer (services tab) and accidentally deleted one of the databases.

I was trying to connect to a database and there were 2 options in the context menu for connecting.

1)Connect
2)Delete

I accidentally hit delete. It did not even ask me for confirmation. Is there anyway to recover the database?

I don't have access to mysql server. I can just connect to the database using mysql workbench.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Backups are an even better idea now, right? Most people with production databases have backups of backups and archives of their backups just to be sure. Everyone eventually screws up something like this, so hopefully you can fix it and learn from it.

Comment: the situation is strange as no production admin will give drop db privs to a developer! - but i hope he fixes this !

Answer (score 1):

If you have the binary logging enabled, then you might have a chance to use it to restore your database.
 Else use an older  backup and restore it !

---

**To find binary logs status :**

```
mysql> show variables like '%bin%';
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                   | Value                |
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                  |
| log_bin                         | OFF                  |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                  |
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                 | 1073741824           |
| sync_binlog                     | 0                    |
+---------------------------------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please guide me..where do i look. I have mysql work bench. The server was configured by someone else

Comment: do you have any backup ? or the only option might be binary logs ? - if they were enabled !

Comment: have a back up of the schema ..and i don't think binary logs were enabled

Comment: so you have a backup ? - ok if so its an easy task ! then

Comment: but i don't have back up of data ..only the schema ..

1) General logs -->On
2)Slow query logs --> On .

does this help?

Comment: No general log and slow log wont do ! check if you have your binary logs enabled

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49500/discussion-between-up-one-and-nikhil)